# Calling jQuery document.ready functions by hand

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I make an AJAX request and want to call all functions that were set up by `$(document).ready()`. How can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a shared function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setup();
});

$.post('/', {}, function() {
    setup();
}, 'json');
```

But if you're using it to re-assign listeners, you would probably be able to get away with assigning them *before* they're created, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).delegate('.my-button', 'click', function() { });
});
```

Using this code, all `.my-button` clicks will be handled by your custom function, regardless of whether the button existed in your DOM upon DOMReady.

Note that:

- `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` can be minimized to `$(function() { ... });`
- If you're using jQuery 1.7+, prefer `.on` over `.delegate`: `$(document).on('click', .my-button', function() { });`
- Prefer narrower context over broader, i.e. `$('#close-parent').delegate` over `$(document).delegate`

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready();
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
function startup() {

    // All your functions in here.

}

$(document).ready(startup);
```

And after your AJAX request is finished:

```
startup();
```

Comment: I think it, you write it. I like this combination... just need to work out how you send over my share of the rep ;)

Comment: You would need to pass a reference to `startup` to `ready`. Currently you're passing the return value of `startup`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering document.ready by hand (which would be bad practice IMHO), make a function that's called `setup` which sets up all listeners etc. and invoke this function when you need to re-apply things etc.

Comment: Thank you, of course, but I have several js files included there and several calls to $(), so it would take a time to separate them into startup function...

Comment: What comes to my mind is setting up a global "setup functions array" to which you add each function to that needs to be executed, in your setup function you just iterate over this array and execute each function, would that work for you?